# Can we install puppet without touching the servers?

Tags: puppet

I heard that puppet need to be installed on server side, not just desktop side, from where we want to launch commands on the servers.

**My question:** Are there any other methods for using puppet? I mean we don't want to install it on server side, just run scripts from our Desktop on the servers..

Comment: Puppet is designed to operate fromthe host it is installed. What you are looking for is a different tool.

Comment: If you're worried about massive deployment of Puppet clients to your different nodes, you can always set up passwordless `ssh` via public keys and have a server-side script loop over your client nodes installing the Puppet client on each.

Comment: Can you expand what you're looking for a bit? We want to help but it's not entirely clear what you're aiming for here. For example what in your minds qualifies as "touching a server"?

Comment: how about adopting a masterless puppet and hosting the puppet binary in shared file system as NFS. you could also host your manifests and data (e.g. hieradata) in the shared file system, and/or still use a version control system for them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use puppet in a master-less mode, but your servers will still need to have the puppet client installed. Details on setting this up are discussed in this blog post titled: [Scaling Puppet with Git](http://bitfieldconsulting.com/scaling-puppet-with-distributed-version-control).

The article shows how you can go about setting up a Git repo to maintain your Puppet manifest files (`.pp`) and then just run Puppet manually to apply them.

#### Example

```
package { "screen":
  ensure => installed,
}
```

Simply save this as something.pp and run it with Puppet:

```
$ sudo puppet -v something.pp 
info: Applying configuration version '1264090058'
notice: //Package[screen]/ensure: created
```

But this method is still very much in line with the client/server model that you'd typically see with a Puppet deployment.

There's also this thread from the puppet-users mailing list titled: [Re: [Puppet Users] Master-less : What do I lose?](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/puppet-users@googlegroups.com/2011-02/msg00180.html) which may shed light on some other options. I also found this blog post titled: [Puppet Without Masters](http://current.workingdirectory.net/posts/2011/puppet-without-masters/) which also discusses options for doing what you're looking for.

I'd also direct you to this post titled: [Configuration management: push vs. pull](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2010/03/configuration-management-push-vs-pull.html) which discusses the differences in the approaches when doing configuration management. Puppet is strictly speaking a pull solution, so what you're proposing will be difficult using it, since what you're looking for sounds more like a push solution from your desktops to your servers.

There are other solutions if you truly want to go with a push methodology but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I will detail [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129318/can-we-install-puppet-without-touching-the-servers#comment209074_129318) here, with my actual suggestion.

My main assumption is that you don't want to install Puppet on the client nodes because of their sheer number. If you can't "touch them" because of a permissions issue, then I doubt you can push configuration at all, whether via Puppet or any other method.

You can configure `ssh` to log in to a machine without a password using `ssh-keygen` like so:

```
[user@host]$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx user@host
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          E++.+. |
|           -./ . |
|      .     = o  |
|       o   o     |
|        X +      |
|       . $ +     |
|          0 .    |
|        . .S     |
|       ..cb..    |
+-----------------+
```

Make sure to leave the passphrase empty (so the script using this `ssh` will need no password).

As a second step, you need to copy the public key to all of the hosts:

```
while IFS= read -r host; do
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub "$host"
done < hostnames_file
```

where I assume `hostnames_file` has one host name per line listing all the hosts you want to configure.

This script will most likely ask for your password as many times as there are hosts but this will happen only once when you're setting up the keys.

If your `user` happens to have their home directory shared among all clients (via NFS for example), you can instead do this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now you should set up passwordless `sudo` access to the `apt-get` command (or `yum` or `pacman` or whatever package manager you choose) for the `user` you have just configured passwordless `ssh` for. Now it's as simple as:

```
while IFS= read -r host;do
    ssh "$host" 'sudo apt-get install puppet' # also, modify puppet.conf
end < hostnames_file
```

Note that you can use this method as a rudimentary form of configuration management as well<sup>*</sup>, but it's much more fragile than using Puppet or Chef or similar.

#### References

- [SSH Login Without Password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)
- [3 Steps to Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Just replace `sudo apt-get install puppet` with whatever command(s) you wish to run on all your nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for a Configuration Management (CM) or Deployment Management (DM) tool for which you don't have to install [agent software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_agent) in remote machines that you want to manage.

Without an agent model, another method must be used to access remote machines, and this is usually SSH, with public key or password authentication.

For this purpose, there are some candidates you can try:

**Ansible**

[Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) uses SSH, no agent required, the configuration files are in `INI` format. Ansible itself is written in Python.

**(R)?ex**

[(R)?ex](https://www.rexify.org/) uses SSH, no agent required, configuration file can be written in plain `Perl`, in `INI` format, or using template like `YAML` or `Template::ToolKit`. (R)?ex itself is written in Perl.

**Fabric**

[Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) uses SSH, no agent required, configuration files are written in pure Python. Fabric itself is written in Python.

**Salt Stack**

[Salt Stack](http://www.saltstack.com/) is another awesome tool, you can use `salt-ssh` to deploy without requiring an agent, although `salt-minion` is also available. Configuration is mostly written in `YAML`. Salt itself is written in Python.

---

A simple demo in my machine, using (R)?ex:

```
$ rex -H localhost uptime
[2014-05-17 00:46:03] INFO - Running task uptime on localhost
[2014-05-17 00:46:03] INFO - Connecting to localhost:22 (cuonglm)
[2014-05-17 00:46:03] INFO - Connected to localhost, trying to authenticate.
[2014-05-17 00:46:04] INFO - Successfully authenticated on localhost.
gnouc
 00:46:04 up  2:35,  4 users,  load average: 0.68, 0.59, 0.56
[2014-05-17 00:46:04] INFO - Exiting Rex...
[2014-05-17 00:46:04] INFO - Cleaning up...
```

**SSH only**

Once you have SSH set up, you can also perform the same functions without these tools, by using `ssh` directly:

```
$ ssh localhost 'echo $HOSTNAME; uptime'
gnouc
 00:51:29 up  2:41,  4 users,  load average: 0.17, 0.33, 0.45
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical puppet model consists of a puppet master and the puppet clients. 
That said, it is possible to skip the puppet master completely and just use the puppet clients by themselves. (Called masterless puppet modules).

To do this, you wrap the `puppet apply` command in a bash script.

Here is a simple example of a masterless puppet manifest which compiles the latest version of redis from source, then creates an RPM.

https://github.com/spuder/fpm-redis

---

Here is a more complex example we use at my company called builder. You can watch the presentation about it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFByexKKkIE

Builder is just a script that any developer can apply on any VM which will automatically install a product suite via puppet. It is closed source, but I will try my best to explain the basic architecture.

It is written so that when the developer executes builder, they are prompted for which version and edition of the software they want to install.

```
$ sudo ./builder.sh
"Welcome to Builder"

1) Enterprise
2) Basic
3) Quit
Please select an edition: 1

"You have selected: Enterprise"

1) 7.5.0
2) 7.6.0
3) 7.7.0
4) 7.8.0
5) Quit
Please select a release: 2

"You have selected 7.6.0, applying manifests"
```

---

One of the advantages of wrapping your puppet manifest in a bash script like this, is that you can simply write your own facter variables which can later be used. Looking at the simple example from github/spuder/fpm-redis :

Prepend the variables with an upper case 'FACTER'

```
cat fpm-redis
#!/bin/bash
export FACTER_REDIS_VERSION='2.8.8'
puppet apply ./manifests/init.pp
```

The puppet manifest can then refer to the lowercase variable (the word 'FACTER_' is stripped off automatically).

```
cat ./manifests/init.pp

class foo {
  file { "${::redis_version}":
      ensure => file,
      content => 'foo'
  }
}
include foo
```

---

Going back at the builder code, it is modularized so that there is a directory for each product that needs to be installed. This way you can define property files.

```
$ tree /tmp/builder
|
build
    \_ Enterprise.prop
    \_ Basic.prop
|
packages
    \_ java_7
      \_ manifests
                 \_ init.pp

    \_ java_6
      \_ manifests
                 \_ init.pp
    \_ foo
      \_ manifests
                 \_ init.pp
|
builder.sh
```

The property files are just bash script that contain environment variables, and also a list of puppet manifests to apply. Sometimes packages need to be installed in a particular order, so they are divided into pre and post operations.

```
$ cat Enterprise.prop

    PRE_APPLY_LIST= "build/java_6/manifests/init.pp \
                     build/foo/manifests/init.pp"
    POST_APPLY_LIST= "build/foobar/manifests/init.pp"
    export FACTER_FOO='bar'
    export FACTER_DB_PASSWORD='correct horse battery staple'

$ cat Basic.prop

    PRE_APPLY_LIST= "build/java_7"
    export FACTER_HERP='derp'
```

Going back to the menu prompt mentioned earlier. Builder generated the list of menu options by iterating over the build directory.

```
$ cat /tmp/builder.sh

# prompt the user for which product
OPTIONS=`ls build/*.prop`
for opt in $OPTIONS
do
  PP_APPLY=$opt
  break
done

# import the variables from the property file
source $PP_APPLY

# install the desired packages
puppet apply $PRE_APPLY_LIST
puppet apply $POST_APPLY_LIST
```

This is a great way to leverage the advantages of puppet, without needing a puppet master.

Comment: If I am not completely misunderstanding the question, the OP already has a Puppet master and would like to push manifests on nodes that don't have a Puppet agent installed.

Comment: @JosephR. The phrase "we don't want to install it on server side" lead me to believe that they already have puppet on their desktops, and don't want to setup a puppet master.

Comment: and "we want to launch commands on the servers" leads me to think that these boxes,  otherwise used as servers,  are actually the clients in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet is designed to manage packages, files, and services. (Called the trifecta). If you want to manage these things without a puppet master, you could use one of the following applications.

---

**kafo**

A ruby gem that takes yaml config files and generates a directory structure and puppet manifests to install any application.

https://github.com/theforeman/kafo

It was created by the makers of [the forman](http://theforeman.org). It is how they generated their installer.

---

**fpm**

[fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) is the best way to quickly create rpm's and deb packages. It can also create stand alone (masterless) puppet manifests. At the time of this writing, it is still experimental.

You didn't specify exactly what type of scripts you are trying to run. If you are managing a package, file, or service, then you likely would have good luck creating applications with kafo.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't available when the question was asked, but for people coming along now, the answer is to use [Puppet Bolt](